# Adding a layer by URL without knowing the layer type In the ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We are providing a service with a map using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. One of the features that we want to provide is the ability to add any web hosted map layer to our map as a map overlay. When someone adds a map layer, we are not currently requiring any selection for layer type which we would like to keep it that way to keep things simple in the UI, but also simple for the user. Currently we can "detect" layer type just from URL format to tell if it is a MapServer, FeatureServer, ImageServer or Tile Map server, but we would like to also support WMS and WFS layers, and potentially other layer types supported by the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (one of the reasons WMS and WFS is difficult to detect just by URL format is that as far as I can tell there is no standard URL format for a WMS or WFS layer)

So, given a URL to any kind of map service, is there any feature available to automatically detect if it's a supported layer type, and if it is a supported layer type what kind of layer it is?

Comment: The way TerriaJS does it is to test [extension](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/main/lib/Models/Catalog/registerCatalogMembers.ts#L223) (for .geojson, .csv, etc links) and [url regexes](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/main/lib/Models/Catalog/registerCatalogMembers.ts#L269) then basically [just try everything](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/main/lib/Models/Catalog/registerCatalogMembers.ts#L341) as a fallback. I don't know if there's anything more useful in the ArcGIS API JS though.

Comment: For the "ArcGIS" layer types (which you already figured out how to handle), you could instead use the fromArcGISServerUrl() method - see 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-Layer.html#fromArcGISServerUrl